# Best way to check if browser supports `.textContent`?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, browser-feature-detection

I want to check if the browser supports `.textContent`

I have thought these options:

1. `if( document.body.textContent ) { }`
2. `if( document.createElement('div').textContent !== void(0) ) { }`

Of course, the first one is simpler, but the problem I see is that maybe the browser calculates all the string, which can be slow if the website is huge.

Then, which one should I choose? Or is there a better option?

**Edit**: I have created a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/checking-textcontent-browser-support)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With...

```
'textContent' in document.body
```

... expression you'll just check a property (textContent) existence in `document.body` object, without actually checking its value.

And yes, it is `false` in IE8.

Comment: Interesting... I thought that `in` could only be used in loops `for...in`

Comment: According to http://jsperf.com/checking-textcontent-browser-support, this is the fastest option (on browsers that support `.textContent`)

Comment: @Oriol [updating the jsperf](http://jsperf.com/checking-textcontent-browser-support/2) to use `document.body.hasOwnProperty('textContent')` shows that it is fastest in Firefox & Chrome. Slightly slower than `in` for IE10.

Comment: @Mottie I think that's enough interesting to post it in an answer.

Comment: @Mottie In the context of this answer, that option is not viable since essentially the only time you want to check for textContent is when the user is on ie8 or lower and it just so happens that ie8 also does not support hasOwnProperty. Checking it in this manner generates an error in ie8 in standards mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2nd option. Far more efficient. I've just done the test.

Note: Raw Test. Speed: 355 ms vs 6 ms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    varasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs

    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsgasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsasdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjs
    asdajfhaskjaskngakjgnaskjgnaskgjasngkajsngakjsg

        <script>
        var d0 = new Date();var n0 = d0.getTime();  
        for(var i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++){

        if( document.body.textContent ) { }


        }var d1 = new Date();   var n1 = d1.getTime();  console.log(n1-n0);


        var array0 =[];
        var d0 = new Date(); var n0 = d0.getTime(); 
        for(var i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++){

        if( document.createElement('div').textContent !== void(0) ) { }



        }var d1 = new Date();   var n1 = d1.getTime();  console.log(n1-n0); 

        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```